# Jquery UI : Use slider for changing element opacity

Tags: opacity, jquery-ui-slider

I come to you because Jquery slider makes me crazy since hours, I've to use it for changing opacity of my div. When I try to add :

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    var canvas = $('#canvas');
    tooltip.text(ui.value);
    canvas.css('opacity', '' + ui.value + '');
},
```

The Handle is blocked and slider stops to work. I'm using piece of code I found here but when I start to edit it, everything breaks.

Here is the Jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/remibenault/cqVPM/302/

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the line of code I added into your repositionTooltip function:

```
    $("#canvas").css("opacity",ui.value);
```

you can find the exemple here : http://jsfiddle.net/cqVPM/305/

Comment: Thank you a lot but tooltip stops to follow the handle when it is used. I already got this problem on other Jsfiddle I found today, there are possibilities to fix this?

Comment: I edit my project, check the fiddle again and tell me if that is what you had in mind :)     Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqVPM/305/

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much Adrien :) You abducted a thorn from my foot!